# Widget Testing not working as expected in Flutter

Tags: flutter, testing, widget-test-flutter

```
  testWidgets('Login Widget Testing', (WidgetTester tester) async {
await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(Child: loginView));
Finder userNameField = find.byKey(Key('username'));
await tester.enterText(userNameField, 'demo');
Finder passwordField = find.byKey(Key('password'));
await tester.enterText(passwordField, 'welcome');
Finder licenceField = find.byKey(Key('licence'));
await tester.enterText(licenceField, 'demo');

await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('btnLogin')));
final errorFinder = find.text(
  'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials',
);
print(errorFinder);
expect(errorFinder, findsNothing);
```

});

onTap api gets call and validate wheather the user exist with above entered credential

1. if user enters invalid credential expected to get error message 'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials'
2. if entered valid credential should navigate to another page

Here now even though the credential is invalid it throws
zero widgets with text "Invalid credentials Please check your credentials" (ignoring offstage widgets)

expected to have one widget

1. if user enters invalid credential expected to get error message 'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials'
2. if entered valid credential should navigate to another page

Here now even though the credential is invalid it throws
zero widgets with text "Invalid credentials Please check your credentials" (ignoring offstage widgets)

expected to have one widget

```
 await tester.pumpWidget(makeTestableWidget(Child: loginView));
    Finder userNameField = find.byKey(Key('username'));
    await tester.enterText(userNameField, 'd'emo);
    Finder passwordField = find.byKey(Key('password'));
    await tester.enterText(passwordField, 'welcome');
    Finder licenceField = find.byKey(Key('licence'));
    await tester.enterText(licenceField, 'demos');

    var foo = find.byKey(Key('btnLogin'));
    await tester.ensureVisible(foo); // <-- here
    await tester.tap(foo);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    final errorFinder = find.text(
      'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials',
    );
    expect(errorFinder, findsOneWidget);
```

was expecting one widget with following text :
'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials'

Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "Invalid credentials Please check your credentials"
(ignoring offstage widgets)>
Which: means none were found but one was expected

//dart code
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wyemZGSP0rrLyMAAo00q4pdJ0nQf0ItX/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Add some `pumpAndSettle()` before ensureVisible and maybe `await tester.testTextInput.receiveAction(TextInputAction.done)` to close the keyboard

Comment: @lsaudon getting this :  ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure was thrown running a test:
Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _TextFinder:<zero widgets with text "" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected

Comment: If your btnLogin is always visible you can use skipOffstage: false or scroll

Comment: Is it possible to share the form code?

Comment: @lsaudon https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wyemZGSP0rrLyMAAo00q4pdJ0nQf0ItX/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to simplify your form.
I didn't use `obx`.
I think your button is not visible.
You need to add a `await tester.pump();` after `await tester.ensureVisible(foo);`.

```dart
  testWidgets('bad', (tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(const MyApp());
    final userNameField = find.byKey(const Key('username'));
    await tester.enterText(userNameField, 'admin');
    final passwordField = find.byKey(const Key('password'));
    await tester.enterText(passwordField, 'admin');
    final licenceField = find.byKey(const Key('licence'));
    await tester.enterText(licenceField, 'refused');
    final foo = find.byKey(const Key('btnLogin'));
    await tester.ensureVisible(foo);
    await tester.pump(); // Add a pump after ensureVisible
    await tester.tap(foo);
    await tester.pump();
    expect(
      find.text('Invalid credentials Please check your credentials'),
      findsOneWidget,
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: it is working if the text  'Invalid credentials Please check your credentials' is hardcoded i was passing loginCtrl.errormsg.value, to make it dynamic show error based on the response any solution to do so...

Comment: I don't think we have the information to answer your problem. Where does the error message come from? If it's coming from a back-end or storage, you probably need to mock it.